# Wowza Streaming Cloud to Detect the PC Web Cam without encoder

Tags: streaming, cloud, live, wowza

I am currently using wowza free trial. I have a website and I need a similar functionality like Facebook live and Instagram live from a single button. What are the possibilities? what things do I need for that? being a developer I have been able to test the wowza API and I am getting a successful response. 
Being able to make a purchase for my company I need to be sure that user can use integrated PC webcam without any encoder. Looking forward to your satisfactory prompt response.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [flash](/questions/tagged/flash) to send Video from webcam to Wowza. Video will encoded by Flash
2. use [webrtc](/questions/tagged/webrtc) send video to Wowza. Video will encoded by Web Browser